# WInJS: Unload x-ms-webview when user navigates away from the page

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winjs

I have a x-ms-webview control in my WinJS App that plays a youtube video.

When I navigate away from the page, the audio from the video continues to play because (I assume) the webview hasn't been unloaded correctly.

What is the best way of removing the webview when a user navigates away from the page?

HTML: `<x-ms-webview id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer"></x-ms-webview>`

JS: `videoPlayer.src = video.VideoURL;`

**EDIT:** I've tried a horrid bodge using the `navigateToString("")` method in the unload event for the page. Setting this property stops the sound from playing but I hope that's not the only option available.

Comment: How are you doing it today? Is your host code by any chance have a reference to the video player (or any internal elements) that might cause it to stick around?

Comment: In the navigation code there is an onNavigated event which calls unload on the page control and WinJS.Utilities.Empty. I assumed that this would handle everything?

Comment: I would expect it to unless there's something holding on to something in the page from the host.

Comment: The only place I reference the webview control in the JS is when I set the src attribute to be the youtube link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another workaround: you can dispose of the WebView element in the PageControl's unload 'handler':

```
(function () {

    var webView,
        page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/webView/webView.html", {
            ready: function (element, something) {

                webView = document.querySelector("#myWebView");
                webView.src = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk5-gCc_4s4";

            },
            unload: function () {
                webView.parentNode.removeChild(webView);
                webView = null;
            }
        });

})();
```

The YouTube video will continue to play for about a minute. When you navigate back to the page with the WebView, the element will be reloaded with that PageControl. I think that your solution to use `navigateToString("")` is the best.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll leave it as is for now but I shall use your technique for another issue I have with Bing Maps in an iframe.Your book is great BTW!

Comment: Thank you for the praise about the book, although I wonder if you're thinking of Kraig Brockschmidt's book. (Kraig is great to work with, incidentally.) If you're working with Bing Maps in an iframe, you might also consider using the Bing Maps SDK (if you haven't already) msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428643.aspx.

Comment: It seems the WebView in WinRT SDK 10.0.10586 still has this CPU and memory leak! It indeed is a leak as loading the same page over an over, will remove all XAML resources from the visual tree, that is they are unloaded, including the webview itself, yet the webview continues to indefinetly operate, i.e. run scripts, etc.

Comment: This is still an issue nearly 2 years later... Any other workarounds @EricSchmidt-MSFT? The answer you provided may or may not dispose the DOM node but it keeps the underlying webview representation which is a massive memory leak for our video-heavy application.